# Why this is showing an error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I read that in typescript :

```
constructor(private <variableName> : Type){}
```

is same as

```
constructor(<variableName> : Type){
  <variableName> = <variableName>;
}
```

Then, why in the below code I'm getting error

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherItem } from '../weather-item';
import { WEATHER_ITEMS } from '../weather.data';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-list',
  templateUrl: './weather-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-list.component.css']
})
export class WeatherListComponent implements OnInit {

   weatherItems : WeatherItem[];

   constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
      _weatherService = _weatherService;
   }

    ngOnInit() {    
       this.weatherItems = this._weatherService.getWeatherItems();
    }
   }
```

Here, in ngOnInit method, I'm getting the error **'Property _weatherService does not exist on type WeatherListComponent'**.
[Code shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZjz5.png)

While, the below code works successfully.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherItem } from '../weather-item';
import { WEATHER_ITEMS } from '../weather.data';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-list',
  templateUrl: './weather-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-list.component.css']
})
export class WeatherListComponent implements OnInit {

  weatherItems : WeatherItem[];

  constructor(private  _weatherService : WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {      
    this.weatherItems = this._weatherService.getWeatherItems();
  }

}
```

[code runs correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVntT.png)

** I tried to go with 'this' keyword in constructor as :

```
constructor( _weatherService : WeatherService) {
    this._weatherService = _weatherService;
  }
```

But now I'm getting error in constructor itself as : 'Property _weatherService does not exist on type WeatherListComponent'[Please check the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPbrf.png)

Comment: you are missing a `this.` without it the code wont know if you are refering to the local variable in the constructor or the class member. You have to help it with that.

Comment: Actually it is `this.<variableName> = <variableName>;`.

Comment: You are still missing the first line of @toskv's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question and attached the code screenshot with error (Its marked as **) I'm getting in constructor itself on using 'this' keyword. Could you check that and point me out where I'm wrong? Thanks again

Comment: Add the line `private _weatherService: WeatherService;` before the constructor.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

In this case:

```
constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
      _weatherService = _weatherService;
   }
```

Inside of the scope of the constructor, `_weatherService` refers to the *parameter* passed to it, **not** to a *class member*. So you are basically setting the value of `_weatherService` to itself.

Now if you do the following:

```
constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
   this._weatherService = _weatherService;
}
```

The compiler correctly complains, as you havent defined a *class member* called `_weatherService`

You could fix that by doing the following:

```
_weatherService: WeatherService; // defaults to public visibility
constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
    this._weatherService = _weatherService;
}
```

As you correctly stated, typescript offers [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), which is just some syntactic sugar to avoid tedious initialization of values.

Bearing this in mind, we can check some other interesting cases:

```
constructor(private _weatherService : WeatherService) {
    this._weatherService = _weatherService;
}
```

This will set the value of the class member `_weatherService` two times: one time through the ts feature and one because of the manual initialization.

```
weatherItems : WeatherItem[];
constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
    this.weatherItems = _weatherService;
}
```

This will set the class member `weatherItems`, but will not define a class member called `_weatherService`. Basically, you can inject a parameter, extract a value from it and store it in a class member, without having to store the reference to that parameter in the class.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you need to add it to your WeatherListComponent referred in your constructor as `this`:

```
constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
  this._weatherService = _weatherService;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same but now its showing error in constructor itself as 'Property _weatherService does not exist on type WeatherListComponent'

Comment: Add a property: `_weatherService : WeatherService` right below `weatherItems`

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor when you are trying to assign your injected service, _weatherService has not yet been instantiated or declared )you have not created the variable _weatherService.

```
 public _weatherService: WeatherService = new WeatherService();


 constructor(_weatherService : WeatherService) {
  this._weatherService = _weatherService;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`constructor(private <variableName> : Type){}`

is equivalent to

```js
private <variableName>: Type;
constructor(<variableName> : Type){
    this.<variableName> = <variableName>;
}
```

You can see a working example in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Test1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20property%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.property%20%3D%20property%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same but now its showing error in constructor itself as 'Property _weatherService does not exist on type WeatherListComponent'

Comment: @user3760959 - Can you show us what you tried? That answer looks OK to me. We may add that the constructor parameter doesn't need to have the same name as the class member.

Comment: @user3760959 I added a link working example in the playground. You can see that it works and what the generated code is. Maybe the problem is somewhere else? Or just an old one. Knowing more about your setup might help.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question and attached the code screenshot with error (Its marked as **) I'm getting in constructor itself on using 'this' keyword. Could you check that and point me out where I'm wrong? Thanks again

Comment: if you don't define it in the constructor you HAVE to define it as a class property. If you don't you'll get that error. Check my example in the playground. The `private <variableName>: Type;` line is not optional. In the end though the constructor one is just a shorthand for the other, in the end the same code gets generated.